# Bootstrap shows only mobile menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason when i try to implant the 'navbar' with Bootstrap it shows me it in mobile mode no matter what.

[image: example what it looks like]

And i cant make it to look like it should on desktop mode. i disabled all other stylesheets besides Bootstrap and still stays the same. so it's not some of my CSS that make this happen.
and the code is raw code from [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com).

what can be the problem?

Comment: Please show the html code

Comment: Absolutely impossible to help if we can't see your code.

Comment: as i said its just the raw code from their site http://codepen.io/ronka/pen/MwXYbQ

parent element is body.

as you can see on codepen it looks how it should. but when i put it in my code it shows like in the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't figure out what you are missing. However I think you might missing some class.Just Guess.

**Navigation Button code:-**

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#yourtarget">
```

**EXAMPLE OF Bootstrap Menu(Collapsing The Navigation Bar)**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```